# Change sql to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next code of an sql query, but i need to adapt it to mysql query, but it gives me an error the the value "number", and i don't know how to change it correctly, if someone knows how can this code work i will appreciate you to answer

```
    Create table SalarioBase(
IdSalario number constraint pk_salariobase primary key,
Salario number)
```

Comment: Pick a type from here: [MySQL Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html)

Comment: When i change it to an integer it shows me the error "syntax error: unexpected 'constraint'"

Comment: Take a look at this [**example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1fa6/1/0). You can choose your preferred datatype.

Comment: Named constraints are specified separately from column names as additional clauses in the query. See the full syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

```
CREATE TABLE `SalarioBase` (
     `IdSalario` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
     `Salario` INT NULL COMMENT '',
     PRIMARY KEY (`IdSalario`)  COMMENT '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

> Create table SalarioBase(
>   IdSalario int constraint pk_salariobase primary key,
>   Salario int)

```
You can change int to float ... etc. if you need.
```

Follows [T-SQL92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt),number is not a basic data type

As far as I know, also your code does not work on ms-sql